# buscar en tiempo real y paginar angularjs

Tags: php, javascript, html, angularjs

tengo un problema con este codigo todo funciona bien pero cuando cambio de pagina el buscador no encuentra resultado

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

// alternate - https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination
// alternate - https://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/paginating-through-client-side-data.html

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 10;
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.q = '';
    
    $scope.getData = function () {
      // needed for the pagination calc
      // https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter
      return $filter('filter')($scope.data, $scope.q)
     /* 
       // manual filter
       // if u used this, remove the filter from html, remove above line and replace data with getData()
       
        var arr = [];
        if($scope.q == '') {
            arr = $scope.data;
        } else {
            for(var ea in $scope.data) {
                if($scope.data[ea].indexOf($scope.q) > -1) {
                    arr.push( $scope.data[ea] );
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
       */
    }
    
    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.getData().length/$scope.pageSize);                
    }
    
    for (var i=0; i<65; i++) {
        $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
    }
}]);

//We already have a limitTo filter built-in to angular,
//let's make a startFrom filter
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="q" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter text">
   
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:q | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
        Previous
    </button>
    {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= getData().length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
        Next
    </button>
</div>


<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: es logico, al cambiar la longitud del array el paginado debe cambiar tambien, la solucion que te doy es que al buscar lo ubiques en la pagina 1, estas redimensionando el array por ende el paginado cambia tambien

Answer (score 0):

Puedes solucionarlo con un ng-change en el input de busqueda, para que la paginacion regrese a la pagina 1 (currentPage=0)

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

// alternate - https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination
// alternate - https://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/paginating-through-client-side-data.html

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 10;
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.q = '';
    
    $scope.getData = function () {
      // needed for the pagination calc
      // https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter
      return $filter('filter')($scope.data, $scope.q)
     /* 
       // manual filter
       // if u used this, remove the filter from html, remove above line and replace data with getData()
       
        var arr = [];
        if($scope.q == '') {
            arr = $scope.data;
        } else {
            for(var ea in $scope.data) {
                if($scope.data[ea].indexOf($scope.q) > -1) {
                    arr.push( $scope.data[ea] );
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
       */
    }
    
    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.getData().length/$scope.pageSize);                
    }
    
    for (var i=0; i<65; i++) {
        $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
    }
}]);

//We already have a limitTo filter built-in to angular,
//let's make a startFrom filter
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="q" ng-change="currentPage=0" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter text">
   
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:q | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
        Previous
    </button>
    {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= getData().length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
        Next
    </button>
</div>


<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```